# GeneratedAssetSymbols error "Ambiguous use of ..." in Xcode 15

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I turned on the new feature for Xcode 15 and now my build is failing. GeneratedAssetSymbols is about 13k lines, of which about 1k are failing.

The failures are all in `SwiftUI.Color` extension. A line like this:

```swift
static var gr150: SwiftUI.Color { .init(.gr150) }
```

The `Found this candidate` points to:

```swift
/// The "gr150" asset catalog color.
static var gr150: AppKit.NSColor {
    #if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        .init(resource: .gr150)
    #else
        .init()
    #endif
}
```

and

```swift
/// The "gr150" asset catalog color resource.
static let gr150 = ColorResource(name: "gr150", bundle: resourceBundle)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Or turn off GeneratedAssetSymbols?

This is for a macOS SwiftUI target app.

Comment: Did you add any of your own custom initialisers to `Color`?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is that you added your own `Color.init` somewhere, that takes an `NSColor`, perhaps because you didn't want to write the `nsColor:` parameter label all the time. e.g.

```
extension Color {
    init(_ color: NSColor) { self.init(nsColor: color) }
}
```

That would cause `Color(.gr150)` to be ambiguous. It could be calling `Color.init(ColorResource)`, or it can be calling your own `Color.init(NSColor)`.

---

Otherwise, I'm not sure why it is ambiguous. You can turn the generation off by setting the "Generate Swift Asset Symbol Extensions" setting off.

[image]

This will still generate GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift, but only the `ColorResource`s and `ImageResource`s, so you can still avoid string literals when using your colors. You just need to do:

```
Color(.gr150)
// or
NSColor(resource: .gr150)
```

Since `NSColor.gr150` is gone, the first one is no longer ambiguous.

If you only need the SwiftUI `Color` extensions, you can still have "Generate Swift Asset Symbol Extensions" on, and only put "SwiftUI" in the "Generate Swift Asset Symbol Framework Support".

[image]

This way, you still get `Color.gr150`, and since `NSColor.gr150` is gone, the generated `.init(.gr150)` will not longer be ambiguous.